# Woo-commerce Variable Regular and Sale price

Tags: categories, product, woocommerce

I am trying to display the regular and sale price of a variable product. I know it can be achieved from get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_regular_price', true); but it isnt working in variable products only a simple product.

I looked into the classes and also saw that woocommerce updates the post meta of _regular_price itself when storing a variable product price.

Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: I answered it myself. In case anyone wants to know, they can using get price html and then use this filter to modify the output...

Comment: [CODE]add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'wpa83367_price_html', 100, 2 );
function wpa83367_price_html( $price, $product ){
    return 'Was:' . str_replace( '<ins>', ' Now:<ins>', $price );
}[CODE]

Answer (score 4):

The best code for solve this is:

```
    #Step 1: Get product varations
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

#Step 2: Get product variation id
$variation_id=$available_variations[0]['variation_id']; // Getting the variable id of just the 1st product. You can loop $available_variations to get info about each variation.

#Step 3: Create the variable product object
$variable_product1= new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

#Step 4: You have the data. Have fun :)
$regular_price = $variable_product1 ->regular_price;
$sales_price = $variable_product1 ->sale_price;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any variation in your product then, you can simple get product price using product ID like:-

```
add_action('init', 'test');

function test() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $product = new WC_Product(268);
    echo $product->get_price();
}
```

If product have variation and each variation have different price then need to get price using variation ID.

Answer (score 0):

That's because variable product is not keeping any price information itself but it is the parent of another kind of child posts named `"product_variation"` each having their own price and variation information. So if you want to do something on price of variable products in a `WP_Query` loop you have to filter your loop through `post_type => 'product_variation'` and then you can access their parent id from their `post_parent` property for getting other related information of those variable products variations such as name, description, images, ...

Here is an example:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'product_variation', // <<== here is the answer
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '_price',
        'order' => 'asc',
        ));

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $pid = $query->post->ID;
    $parent = $query->post->post_parent;
    $price = get_post_meta($pid, '_price', true);
    $regular_price = get_post_meta($pid, '_regular_price', true);
    $sale_price = get_post_meta($pid, '_sale_price', true);
    $title_product = get_the_title($parent);
    $title_variation = get_the_title($pid);
    echo "$title_variation: $price <br />";
}
```